# Trouble animating CCLabelTTF using opacity property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following piece of code :

```
CCLabelTTF *start = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"What Car was that?" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
start.position = ccp( size.width * 1.5 / 4, size.height * 3 / 4 );
[start setOpacity:0.0];
[self addChild:start];

[self fadeText:start duration:1.5 curve:0 x:0 y:0 alpha:255.0];
```

and here is how fadeText is defined :

```
- (void)fadeText:(CCLabelTTF *)progress duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
             curve:(int)curve x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y alpha:(float)alpha
{
    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    progress.opacity = alpha;
    //[progress setOpacity:alpha];
    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

for some reason the effect takes place without the animation, so the text shows (hence opacity changes to 255) but it is not animated!

Answer (score 0):

Alpha ranges from 0 to 1. If you specify 255, it will reach 1 very quickly and stay there. So just pass `alpha:1` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UIView animation, you can use `CCFadeTo` function to fade a `CCLabelTTF`.

```
id fade = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1 opacity:200];
```

give this fade animation as runAction to the label.